# How does ATC ask a pilot to resume flying a published SID / STAR?

Tags: air-traffic-control, phraseology

Let's say that you are cleared for and are flying the ZZOOO2 departure out of KSAN and you get vectored off of the departure before you complete it.

At some point, ATC wants to put you back onto the departure.

How would ATC ask you to get back on the ZZOOO2 departure, adhering to all altitude and speed restrictions along the way? Is there standard phraseology that exists?

Answer (score 0):

More than likely they give you vectors to fly to get you back on course, or have you proceed directly to the next waypoint. Really depends on where you got turned away and your intended direction of flight afterwards.